# Delete Command Not working in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to delete a particlular ear files while running my installer... 
I have used the  following command to delete the files

```
Delete "${fileLoc}\*.ear"
```

But this command is not working for me. I dont know the reason... Could you please suggest how to delete particular extension files in NSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the file path is incorrect, or the file cannot be deleted (for various reasons).

- to check the file path, you can add a

  `DetailPrint "delete ${fileLoc}\*.ear"`

  to see at run time if it tries to delete the correct files
- if the path is correct, it may be impossible to delete the file

  - if the file is in currently open / in use by another process, you can try to mark the file as being deleted on the next system starty by using the `REBOOTOK` parameter for `Delete` :`

    `Delete /REBOOTOK "${fileLoc}\*.ear"`
  - because you have a problem with user rights management in a system using UAC (Vista, Win7,...): the current account does not have the right to delete the file (e.g. because it is in a system-protected area like `Program files` and you need to run elevated (run as administrator) to be able to delete the files